# Kill activity when already active

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, notifications

For a notification I am using an Intent to start an Activity. However, when that activity is already active, it comes to the front.

I don't want this to happen, but I'd like it to be restarted. I don't want multiple instances, so in the manifest I added launchMode singleTask.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY` in your intent. it doesn't keep the activity in stack.
For more details read [this](http://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/)